# Exclude a specific category from breadcrumbs

Tags: category, breadcrumbs

Say I place a product in the following categories:

> Microsoft

and

> Software > Operating Systems > Windows

At the moment, all products when accessed through the "Windows" category display the following as a breadcrumb:

> Home > Microsoft > Product Name

I don't want this. I want to completely exclude the "Microsoft" category from showing up in the breadcrumbs. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: by default magento will show `Home > Microsoft > Product Name` when you access the product via category `Microsoft` and shows `Software > Operating Systems > Windows`, when you access the product via category `Operating Systems > Windows`.

Comment: Specifically, is there a way of stopping this behaviour?

Comment: You just need this only for this category `mircosoft` ? and also are you sure all products that comes under `micorsoft` will available under `operationg System > Windows`

Comment: I want to completely exclude the "Microsoft" category from showing up in the breadcrumbs. No, I'm not sure about that specifically, but I do know for sure that the products will be showing up in one other category. It might be Software > Operating Systems > Linux as an example.

Answer (score 1):

edit your breadcumbs file and in breadcumb file write following code

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

$url=explode("/",$currentUrl);

if (in_array("Microsoft", $url))

{
   your custome breadcrumbs code
}

else{
normal breadcrumbs code
}
```